# CSS background-position 0.1s linear;

Tags: css, css-animations, background-position

What does the linear attribute mean in CSS?

```
 background-position 0.1s linear;
```

I am looking at this code and am unfamiliar with the linear attribute.  How does this change the gradient of a button?

```
.btn:hover {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-position: 0 -15px;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -ms-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The word **linear** represents the easing functionality used in your css transition - this is formally known as a "transition-timing-function". In this case **linear** is telling the css that this element will maintain the same speed throughout the animation of this Transition.

When we specify a transition-timing-function we are defining a curve graph that represents the speed throughout the animation.

[Take a look at the MDN documentation here - you can see a list of the other options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function)

To get other interesting animation effects you can try "ease-in" or "ease-out" which represent animations that start slower and speed up or start quickly and slow down.

Using `cubic-bezier(start, mid1, mid2, end)` you can even define your own easing if you were so inclined.  The four values represent speed at Start MidPoint1 MidPoint2 and End of the animation.